# Google Cloud Storage - switch projects

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I recently started using Google Cloud Storage. Initially I created a dummy project while installing the Cloud SDK. Now I am working on another project. The `gsutil` is still pointing to my previous project. How do I make it point to my new project??

P.S. I know there is an option of using `-p` argument, but this does not work on all commands.

Comment: You can also look at some of the solutions to a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/46770900/311525

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got this fixed by running `gcloud init` and following the commands to reinitialize the configuration.

Answer (score 97):

To change the default project that gcloud (and gsutil) use in a gcloud installation, you should do this:

`gcloud config set project desired-project-id-here`

You can view your current settings with `gcloud config list`.

You can view all configurations available with `gcloud config configurations list`.

You can then switch to an alternate configuration with `gcloud config configurations activate [NAME]`

Comment: Is it `desired-project-name-here` or `desired-project-id`? When I tried with name, It returned error and suggested using this command: `gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID`

Answer (score 3):

For scripting, it's safer to set the project just for one gsutil call:

```sh
CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT=your-project-id gsutil # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.

First, you could repeat the gsutil setup. Just run `gsutil config`.

Alternatively, if you don't want to run through setup again, gsutil's config lives in a file called `.boto`. In Linux, it'll be in your home directory. It's a readable config file. Open it up, scroll down to the line `default_project_id =`, and change the project after the equals sign.

Edit: I missed that you were using gsutil as part of the gcloud suite. My suggestion only applies if you've installed gsutil directly. Travis's suggestion is the right one if you have gcloud installed.

Comment: I did not try this, might as well help. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to setting a default project in `gcloud` using
`gcloud config set project $GCP_PROJECT_NAME`

`gsutil`, just like `gcloud`, respects the environment variable 
`CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT`

you can use `export CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT=$GCP_PROJECT_NAME` and use `gsutil` in the new project

Comment: I think it is GCP_PROJECT_ID not name of project. Command will be `gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID`